# Is "From When" properly used here?

Tags: word-usage, usage

Does the below sentence depict the correct usage of ***from when***?

> This is the car *from when* the current elderly studied at that high school.

If I'm not mistaken, *from when* means *from the time*.

Comment: Check your sentence. There's something wrong with it

Comment: Yes, it does seem like that, if as said by @RonaldSole, there is nothing incorrect in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the car from when the current elderly studied at that high school.

This original sentence seems unnatural.  'From the time' is a better phrase.  I also suggest using 'were studying' to give a definite timeframe.

"This is the car 'from the time' the current elderly 'were studying' at that high school."